# Deducing an order 3 numerical method to solve initial-value-problems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, runge-kutta-methods

This question may become as an easy one but for us students is really important to understand a question before trying to answer it.

I am asked to

> "deduce, using numerical derivation, an order 3 method to solve Initial-Value-Problems"
>   $$y'=f(x,y)$$
>   $$y(x_0)=y_0$$

EDIT:
My question is: **"What would anyone understand from that question?"**

Should I deduce a new method or an existing one (say RK3)?

Thanks in advance.
Hope you can shed me some light to understand the question

Comment: Questions about clarifying instructions on assignments aren't things that we (or anyone who didn't make the assignment) can answer with certainty.  But I highly doubt you're expected to come up with something entirely new.  Perhaps "new" in the sense that it wasn't covered in class would make sense.

Comment: Thanks for answering @tilper. I understand what you are saying, and you are totally right. Maybe I didn´t express myself correctly. I meant **"What would anyone understand for that question?"**. I´ll ask my teacher though! (It is just I haven´t been able to reach her and wanted to get something done)

Comment: Is "numerical derivation" more figuratively in the sense of numerical experiments or more literally in the sense of computing divided differences to compute approximate Taylor polynomials?

Comment: @LutzL, is the latter!

Comment: Then again you could use an order 4 approximation of the derivative $y'(t)$ using values $y(t+kh)$, see linear multi-step methods, or the formulas $y''=f_t+f_yf$, $y'''=f_{tt}+2f_{ty}f+f_yf_t+f_{yy}f^2+f_y^2f$ for the Taylor polynomial of $y(t+h)$.